# Internal queues in DB2 similar to AQ JMS for Oracle

Tags: db2, jms, message-queue

Are there any internal queues in DB2 similar to AQ JMS queue in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Many companies use IBM's MQ series products for message queueing, under the Websphere branding, and there are functions to access queues in SQL, as well as from java and 'c' based programming languages .

The Websphere MQ products are separately licensed from Db2 although can interact with Db2, and Db2 can interact with MQ products via various interfaces.

The MQ products are multi-platform (Z/OS, i-series, Linux / Unix /Windows).

Refer to the [MQ documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v91.doc/WelcomePagev9r1.htm) for details about these MQ products.

For developers there is an [MQ resources](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-downloads/) page with downloads.

[SQL interfaces documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061230.html)

Other vendors queueing products, and open source messaging products, may also have Db2 bindings directly or indirectly from java.